# An apple garden claims that only 3 percent of its apple have a brown spot,

Tags: binomial-distribution

An apple garden claims that only 3 percent of its apple have a brown spot, the apples are sold in a lot of 2000. the garden agrees to take back any lot that contains more than 80 apples with spots.

Let $X$ denote the number of apples in a lot that has a brown spot, we may assume $X\sim Bin(n,p)$

(a) What is $n$ and $p$?

so $n= 2000 \times \frac{3}{100}=60$?

could any one tell me what is $p$? Thanks

Comment: Not quite: $n=2000$ and $p=\frac{3}{100}$.  So $60=np$ is the expected number of apples with a brown spot

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  $n = 2000, p = 0.03.$